# Can't create Windows Server Failover Cluster. Static address was not found on any cluster network

Tags: powershell, azure, cluster-computing, azure-resource-manager, windows-server

I'm trying to create a Windows Server Failover Cluster on Windows Server 2016 in Azure, using this article https://clusteringformeremortals.com/2016/04/23/deploying-microsoft-sql-server-2014-failover-clusters-in-azure-resource-manager-arm/
However, when I execute `New-Cluster -Name sql-sql-cls -Node sql-sql-0,sql-sql-1 -StaticAddress 10.0.192.101 -NoStorage` I get `New-Cluster : Static address '10.0.192.101' was not found on any cluster network.` My VM1 has 10.0.192.5 IP, and VM2 has 10.0.192.6 IP. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a load balancer to the same subnet as the network cards that clister is on and use the ip address that gets assigned to the load balancer.

Comment: I do have a load balancer present, within the same subnet. And when I use load balancer's IP for creation of a cluster, it is getting deployed successfully. But, I create a cluster so I can create SQL Server AlwaysON Availability Group, and it requires to create a listener. But then listener reports error during deployment https://pastebin.com/xYC7NVWq according to some people on internet (can't find the link anymore) Cluster IP address and SQL Listener must have different IP addresses.

Comment: In other words, how do I go about Cluster and SQL Listener at the same time?

Comment: it is a real pain but doable :) - on your load balancer add two ip addresses, setup the cluster with one then the listener with the other. The address that is the listener setup a backend pool to your nic's and a probe going to the cluster. The probe is typically 59999 and you need to also add that to the cluster once you have done a "alter ag add listener"

Comment: see step 6 of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-create-failover-cluster it is essential for the load balancer to work (also not well documented is the frontend ip *needs* to be marked as a floating ip

Comment: Well, I made a typo, used 10.0.192.101 instead of 10.192.0.101 Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The fix seems to be that all the nodes must have a Default Gateway IP address. It doesn't have to be a real gateway, just an IP in the same range.

And now the cluster is created with no problems. After the cluster is running, you can remove the gateway IP address.